# Webform with File upload field throwing "... field is required" error

Tags: forms, webforms, files

I have created a Webform, which has two file fields (i.e. Attach document 1 and Attach document 2). Both of them are mandatory and files are to be uploaded in the "Private" folder.

Now when someone attaches the files and submits the form, it throws error messages "Attach document 1 field is required" and "Attach document 2 field is required". If I invoke the validation, then it works. I have checked in the server and the files are uploaded properly. So I think it is "Webform" or "Form" issue.

Comment: I answered this below, but you should really try searching the issue queue on the drupal.org page for a module before posting here in general.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue and applying the patch from  mentioned by squarecandy should solve the problem. The patch for 2678822 is included in Drupal 7.50. I would agree one should check the issue list first. However I think the information here, including from me adds value by summarising where the fix can be found: the solution in  https://www.drupal.org/node/2678822 is now in Drupal 7.50

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by applying the patches found here:

- #49 https://www.drupal.org/node/2675170#comment-10908802
- #22 https://www.drupal.org/node/2678822#comment-10926613

This will hopefully be resolved just by updating for future versions of drupal core and webform.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I had the same issue as the original poster. I updated from Drupal 7.44 to 7.50. At 7.44 I was able to reproduce the issue 100% of the time, once upgraded to 7.50, the issue does not now occur, on the basis of my testing so far. So I would conclude 7.50 fixes the issue. The issues you mention relate to a fix for one of theses - issue 2678822 which has been included in 7.50. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.50

Answer (score -1):

I experience the same problem (using Webform 4.1). I found out that this issue only appears when I have the File entity (7.x-2.0-beta1) module enabled.